# Android button with selector background doesn't load landscape drawables

Tags: android, xml, button, selector, drawable

I've set up a button with an xml selector background. The drawables are located in different versions at drawable-xhdpi and at drawable-land-xhdpi.
Problem is on rotation change to landscape the buttons aren't assigned with the land version.

the button looks like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/home_button"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/xml_selector_home"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fwd_button"
                            android:layout_weight="1">
                    </Button>
```

the button drawable looks like this:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/homeon"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/homeoff"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the ladscape folder to

```
drawable-xhdpi-land
```

Comment: mm.. doesn't work. when i tried using java to load textures programmaticaly on touch events it knew to draw the textures from drawable-land-xhdpi. for some reason xml selector mechanism doesn't.